Partial differential equation. Solve the problem using Green's function
Please help me find a way to decide which direction to move in.
Task:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + f(x, t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) |_{t=0} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) |_{x=0} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) |_{x=l} = 0
\end{equation}
Write the solution using the Green's function.
My course of decision:

I am using the Laplace transform:
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} e^{-st}dt = \frac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} e^{-st}dt = s \overline{u}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x,t) e^{-st}dt = \overline{f}(x,s)
\end{equation}
2. Write down the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x^2} - s \overline{u} = - \overline{f}(x,s)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\overline{u}(0, s) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\overline{u}(l, s) = 0
\end{equation}

Next, I decided to try this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x^2} - s \overline{u} = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lambda^2 - s = 0, \lambda = \pm \sqrt(s) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\overline{u} = C_1 e^{\sqrt(s)x}+ C_2 ^{-\sqrt(s)x}
\end{equation}

I understand that this solution will not work and I try to write it using the Green function:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial^2 \overline{G}}{\partial x^2} + s \overline{G} = \delta(x-s)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\overline{G}(0, s) = 0,
\overline{G}(l, s) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial^2 \overline{G}}{\partial x^2} + s \overline{G} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
\overline{G} = 
 \begin{cases}
   C_1 e^{\sqrt(s)x}+ C_2 ^{-\sqrt(s)x} &0 \leq x < \xi\\
   C_3 e^{\sqrt(s)x}+ C_4 ^{-\sqrt(s)x}&\xi < x \leq l
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\overline{G}(0, s) = C_1+C_2 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\overline{G}(l, s) = C_3 e^{\sqrt(s) l}+C_4 e^{-\sqrt(s)l}= 0
\end{equation}

Using conditions:
\begin{equation}
\overline{G}(\xi + 0, \xi) = \overline{G}(\xi - 0, \xi), 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\overline{G'_x}|_{x = \xi + 0} = \overline{G'_x}|_{x = \xi - 0} + \frac{1}{a_0}, a_0 = -1 
\end{equation}
I get the equations:
\begin{equation}
C_1 e^{\sqrt(s) \xi}+C_2 e^{-\sqrt(s)\xi}= C_3 e^{\sqrt(s)\xi}+C_4 e^{-\sqrt(s)\xi}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{s} (-C_1 e^{\sqrt(s) \xi}+C_2 e^{-\sqrt(s)\xi}+ C_3 e^{\sqrt(s)\xi}-C_4 e^{-\sqrt(s)\xi}) = -1
\end{equation}
Am I doing the right thing?

Do we know anything else about the function $f(x,t)$? For instance, do we have $f(0,t) = f(l,t) = 0$?

Nothing is known about f(x, t).

Section 8.3 in (my copy of) Haberman's Applied Partial Differential Equations, it is explained how to solve this equation using a generalized Fourier expansion (assuming $f$ is regular enough such that a smooth solution exists).

Not an answer, but extended comment.
The PDE
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + f(x,t)$$
with initial condition $u(x,0)=0$ and boundary conditions $u(0,t)=0 \land u(L,t)=0$
has the general solution
$$u(x,t)=\int_0^t \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n(\tau)\cdot \sin \left(n\pi \frac{x}{L}\right)\cdot {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{\pi^{2} n^{2} \left(t-\tau \right)}{L^{2}}}\; \mathrm{d}\tau$$
with Fourier coefficients
$$A_n(t)=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x,t)\cdot \sin(n \pi \frac{x}{L})\; \mathrm{d}x$$
Example
$$f(x,t)\to \sin(\pi \frac{x}{L})\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-\sigma t}$$
we get the solution
$$u(x,t)\to \frac{L^2}{\sigma L^2-\pi^2}\cdot \sin(\pi \frac{x}{L})\cdot \bigg(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi^2}{L^2}t}-\mathrm{e}^{-\sigma t}\bigg)$$
Plot solution with $L=1, \sigma=2$:
See also MATLAB implementation MSE_Q5011515

